# How to make padding to max sequence lengths in batch with tensorflow dataset api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-length-array

I have for example

```
123
1234
12345
1234556
1234567890
```

It is easy to make global padding like this

```
0000000123
0000001234
0000012345
0001234556
1234567890
```

But I wanna padding in every generated by dataset api batch.
For example with batch size 3 it take 3 random samples

```
123
1234
12345
```

And pad it like this

```
00123
01234
12345
```

I can do it in numpy for example, but this is how batches constructed in tf api:

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
data = data.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=len(y)))
data = data.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
data = data.prefetch(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the padded_batch method.

```py
data.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=max_shape)
```

where max_shape is the size of the padded tensor you want.

I believe that this will append trailing zeros instead of leading zeros, but it is probably still suitable for your purpose.

**EDIT**

Complete working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def gen():
    yield (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(1))
    yield (np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array(0))

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32))
data = data.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=2))
data = data.padded_batch(10, padded_shapes=([None], []))
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(data.output_types, data.output_shapes)
batch = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.make_initializer(data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    batch_out = sess.run(batch)
    print(batch_out)
```

Comment: I  tried it like this
data = data.padded_batch(
        batch_size,
        padded_shapes=([None, None], [None]),
        drop_remainder=True
    )
but got error
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([[-264.],...

Comment: I am not sure if your error is related. I have updated my answer to provide a full working example. You may need to adjust depending on the shape of your real data.

Comment: Maybe it somehow related to from_tensor_slices
I make notebook with your code and error
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BE795SbJ4fpqkjCGDsoGW96Ibgk6OoWp

Comment: The from_tensor_slices will not work for the variable-dimension ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you could do:

```py
import os

data = """123
1234
12345"""

lines = data.splitlines()
max_len = max((len(i) for i in lines))

lines = (i.rjust(max_len, '0') for i in lines)
data = os.linesep.join(lines)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
00123
01234
12345
```

Comment: Well yes, i can do it it numpy for example, but have no idea how to do it in tensorflow.
Added tensorflow dataset code to question. Batch constructed on second line, it is tensor object.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you can use keras pad_sequences:

```
sequence = np.array([[1,2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6]])  

tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequence, padding='pre', value=0)  

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],  
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],  
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: if the sequence is like this ```sequence = np.array([[3,2], [5, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6]]) ```, is it possible to use the first value from each row for the value argument to get the following??
```array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2], [5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])```